# Node.js: Howto close response/request while retrieving data (chuncks)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building an application in node.js wich loads several pages an analyses the contents.

Because node.js sends chunks I can analyse the chunks. If a chunk contains for example index,nofollow I want to close that connection and go on with the rest.

```
var host  = 'example.com',
    total = '',
    http  = require('http');

var req = http.request({hostname: host, port: 80, path: '/'}, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        total += chunk;
        if(chunk.toString().indexOf('index,nofollow') == -1) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            /*
             * WHAT TO DO HERE???
             * how to close this res/req?
             * close this request (goto res.end or req.end????
             */
        }
    }).on('end', function() {
        // do stuff
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    // do stuff
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

The only thing I can't figure out is to quit that connection. Or stop retrieving data because i don't need it..

req.end(); doesn't work.. it keeps continuing with retrieving data/chunks..
(in my test I get 14 chunks, but at the first chunk I already know i don't need the other chunks, so I want to quit the request/response).

I now have a boolean that skips analyzing the others chunks, but in my opinion I'm better of skipping retrieving the data?

What function to call? Or is it impossible because it needs to retrieve everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet, putting this in your `else` block should work: `res.removeAllListeners('data');`

Basically your `res` is a child of `EventEmitter` Object. By calling `removeAllListeners('data')` on it, all the handlers which are bound to `data` event will be removed and the callback won't execute anymore. But you will still have to wait for all the data events to pass before `end` or `error` events are emitted on the request.

Also read nodejs [EventEmitter documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_event) for more info.

#### Update:

You might as well try and emit `end` or `close` event on `res` object in your else block, like this: `res.emit('end');` or `res.emit('close');`. The [documentation on clientRespone](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_clientresponse) object for `end` event says that it is

> Emitted exactly once for each response. After that, no more 'data' events will be emitted on the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm. I analyse the chuncks, so if analyzing isn't needed i want to skip it. Mission accomplished! I'll be digging deeper into the EventEmitter and Listeners.

Comment: Even better. That was what i tried, only at the wrong way. I tried res.end(). But that crashes. res.emit('end') works. It only reads the first chunck and then goes to the end.. futher no chuncks are read. The other option works also by the way. But I will stick to the emit.

Comment: Right, you can `end` a response object only when you are a server. In other words, you can `end` only a `ServerResponse`. The `response` object you have received inside `http.request` callback is a `ClientResponse` object. You can only listen to the `end` event and not call `end()` on the object itself. However, it being an `EventEmitter` we can emit the `end` event and fool the object into believing that `response` has ended, when in fact, the server might still be sending response, no `data` events will be fired post `end` event.