# How to fix 'headers already sent' error in node

Tags: node.js, express, ldap

So I'm trying to create a node app that calls an ldap serve and to authenticate users. In the code below, the app successfully connects to the server and processes the request. But when I try to send a response back, I get this error: 
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

I'm not really sure why this is occurring. I'm pretty new to node, express, and ldap

```
// ldapjs required for ldap connection
const ldap = require('ldapjs');

//express required for exposing endpoints
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const assert = require('assert');

var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://someserve.com'
});

//Search filter for users in the directory
var opts = {
  filter: '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))',
  scope: 'sub',
};

//General Ldap serch user
var UserName = '123.test.com';
var Pass = '123longpass'

//Base URL
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('hello from node')
});

//Get all ldap users
app.get('/api/ldapUsers', (req, res) => 
{
    client.bind(UserName, Pass, function (err) 
    {
        client.search('DC=sdf,DC=sdfa,DC=gdfgd', opts, function (err, search) 
        {
            search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) 
            {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                var users = entry.object;
                console.log(users);

                res.json(users);
                res.end(); 
            });
        });
    });

   // client.unbind( err => {
   //     assert.ifError(err);
   // });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: You don't need to call `res.end();` since `res.json(..);` calls `res.end` internally. And calling `res.end` twice causes this error.

Comment: I tried removing res.end() and I still get the same error. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: `search.on` is an event listner, so maybe try removing the listener? `removeAllListeners('searchEntry')` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459644/node-js-howto-close-response-request-while-retrieving-data-chuncks

Answer (score 0):

searchEntry event is called once for each found item which means you are calling res.json multiple times.

Try this:

```
app.get('/api/ldapUsers', (req, res) => 
{
    client.bind(UserName, Pass, function (err) 
    {
        client.search('DC=sdf,DC=sdfa,DC=gdfgd', opts, function (err, search) 
        {
            var users = [];
            search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                users.push(entry.object); 
            });
            search.on('end', function (entry) {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                console.log(users);

                res.json(users);
                res.end(); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```